# query an IList type object using Any element

Tags: c#, linq

Why the code below returns nothing when I try to query an `IList` type object?

```
IList<Person> personRecord = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person{ Name = "Samuel"},
        new Person{ Name = "Kenny Sammy"},
        new Person{ Name = "Jame Sam Lee"}
    };

var names = from b in personRecord
            where personRecord.Any(d => d.Name == "Sam")
            select b;

return names.ToList();
```

Comment: Probably because no `Person` has a `Name` property equal to "Sam"

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `Any` simply use the condition in `Where` clause like:

```
var names = from b in personRecord 
            where b.Name ==  "Sam"
            select b;
```

or with a method syntax:

```
var names = personRecod.Where(b=> b.Name == "Sam");
```

If you are looking **to match partial contents** then use `Contains` like:

```
var names = personRecod.Where(b=> b.Name.Contains("Sam"));
```

To compare partial content with ignoring case use `IndexOf` like:

```
var names = personRecod.Where(b=> b.Name.IndexOf("Same", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Any` returns a boolean, true/false, for whether any item in that collection satisfies your condition. If you changed your `var names` to the type you expected to receive (`string`) then you'd receive an error highlighting this.

As has been stated, what you are looking for is just the `.Where` method, or possibly a `.FirstOrDefault` or `.First`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the third item (as it's the only one having a name containing the complete word 'Sam') then:

```
var names = personRecord
    .Where(p => p.Name.Split(new char[] {' '}).Contains("Sam"));
```